# What is the difference between rate limiting and back pressure?

Tags: rate-limiting

What is the difference between rate limiting and back pressure? Is it mainly that rate limiting is the client slowing down on its own and back pressure is the service dropping requests to slow down?

Comment: I found the explanation in this article particularly useful: [Traffic Shedding, Rate Limiting, Backpressure, Oh My!](https://medium.com/expedia-group-tech/traffic-shedding-rate-limiting-backpressure-oh-my-21f95c403b29)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rate limiting detects that some action is happening too much in some time frame, and prevents it from happening again until that time frame is over.

For instance, say I have an application that sends an email every time an error is generated. The application talks to a queue that gets polled multiple times a second. So if there is a misconfiguration of the queue then the application can generate thousands of emails in an hour. Adding rate limiting can keep track of the number of error emails sent within a time frame and stop sending emails when the count gets high enough.  Or the application could back off polling the queue for some time interval.

Back pressure means that the system refuses to take more work. Unlike rate limiting there is no set time where the application resumes taking on work, it depends on the application detecting it has capacity.

If I  have an application that receives work through a fixed size blocking queue, then, once the queue fills up, anything that tries to put  a new entry in the queue will wait until the queue can make room for it.  That way the application doesn’t take more work than it can manage, causing it to run out of memory or otherwise getting into a bad state.

Comment: but in that second case, doesn't it means that you have a rate limit in your system and due to that the requests are placed in the queue until your system is able to handle it so you will not lose them? in my mind, "back pressure" was something like: "I don't have enough resources to handle this request so instead of trying to handle this, I'll send a 503 response for instance". am I wrong?

Comment: @JuanFontes: I think rate limit means there is a time frame. For my second example there is no specific time frame, no work gets added until the existing work gets processed, no matter how long it takes. But yes back pressure means you’re refusing work.

Comment: I got it, thanks for the explanation @Nathan Hughes!

Answer (score 0):

I guess "throttling" has fallen out of favor...there used to be all kinds.  I guess these relatively recent developments are a better way of describing what might happen and the associated remedies.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).